# How to use an array with switch in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement

So my problem is that I'm trying to get the array I get after hand1[o] (5 numbers taken randomly from the first array of cards[]. Into a switch in order to detect if it's a flush.
For example if switch of hand1[1] - hand1[0] = 1; hand1[2] - hand[1] = 1... etc
               printf("flush from 1~5").

However, tbh, I'm not even sure what to put inside the parentheses of switch() or the void corrida().
I tried placing hand1[] or hand1[] but it says that hand1 isn't a constant value.

P.S. I know some things are in spanish (since this is for a spanish class)

```
void baraja();
void jugadores();
void jugadores(k);
int cards[52] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13 };
int hand1[5];
int x, y;
int l, k, z;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    baraja();
    jugadores();
}

void baraja()
{

for (l = 1; l <= 52; l++)
{
    x = rand() % 52;
    y = rand() % 52;
    int temp = cards[x];
    cards[x] = cards[y];
    cards[y] = temp;
}

printf("La baraja revuelta es:\n");
for (k = 0; k <= 51; k++)
{
    printf("%d  ", cards[k]);
}
printf("\n\n");
 }

 void jugadores(k)
 {
int o, n = 5;
printf("Tus cartas son:\n");
for (o = 0; o <= 4; o++)
{
    k = rand() % 52;
    printf("%d  ", cards[k]);
    hand1[o] = cards[k];
}
printf("\n\n");

for (o = 0; o < n ; o++)
{
    for (z = 1; z < (n - o); z++)
    if (hand1[z - 1] > hand1[z])
    {
        int temp = hand1[z - 1];
        hand1[z - 1] = hand1[z];
        hand1[z] = temp;
    }
}

printf("Tus cartas en orden incremental son:\n");
for (o = 0; o <= 4; o++)
{
    printf("%d  ", hand1[o]);
}
printf("\n\n");
 }

 void corrida()
 {
switch (hand1)
{
case (hand1[1] - hand1[0] = 1) :

}
 }
```

Comment: I don't believe `switch` is the correct choice here.

Comment: Do you know any function that could help me out here? The problem is im starting fundamentals of programming so i've only learned if and switch for "conditions"/

Comment: `case` labels need to have constant values `case (hand1[1] - hand1[0] = 1) :` doesn't have a constant value. Besides that `switch (hand1)` doesn't make sense, the value of `hand1` never changes.

Comment: Yeah, that's the error that I get and yeah about that switch (hand1) I do realize it's not correct. tbh I'm not 100% sure what to put inside the parentheses in switch and outside of switch

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? this is C.

Comment: You may want to read the reference for [switch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `switch` correctly.

The idea of a switch statement is to take an expression that could have multiple values, and then do something different on each possibility. In C++, you're only allowed to switch on things that are fundamentally integers: `int` or `char` types<sup>1</sup>, not strings (Which Java will let you do) or arrays as you're trying to do here.

However, `switch` isn't appropriate to use here, because you're interested in comparing the values of multiple expressions simultaneously. You would be much better off using an `if` structure with multiple expressions. Something like:

```
if(hand1[1] - hand1[0] == 1 && hand1[2] - hand1[1] == 1 && ...)
```

You could also make this more readable by using a short "flush-finding" algorithm, like below:

```
bool hasFlush(){
    for(int i = 1; i < length-of-hand1; i++){
        if(hand1[i] - hand1[i-1] != 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that I've not tested this code; this is just a general idea. Note that, as Baldrickk points out in comments, this method will only work if `hand1` is sorted in ascending order. The example hand `{2, 4, 3, 5, 1}` will not be detected as a flush, even though it clearly is one. There are ways to modify the algorithm to make this work without sorting.

---

<sup>1</sup> I believe you could also switch on `bool`, but I don't know why you'd want to.

Comment: nvm... I used || which is or...
It worked! Thank you so much C:

I did do the condition as you told me but the only problem that seems to happen is that it does what's in the if () {} even if the conditions arent met.
 if (hand1[1] - hand1[0] == 1 || hand1[2] - hand1[1] == 1 || hand1[3] - hand1[2] == 1 || hand1[4] - hand1[3] == 1)
 {
  printf("Tienes una Corrida del %d al %d! Felicidades\n", hand1[0], hand1[4]);
 }
prints it even if it's not a flush (1,2,3,4,5... etc.)

Comment: is not ||(or) man, is &&(and)

Comment: Note that both for the `for` loop and the long `if` (using `&&` to make it work) methods here require the hand to be sorted. If they are not, it won't detect them.  You could do it with a nested for loop (2 levels)

Comment: @Baldrickk Excellent point; I've added a note

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement is composed of two parts: the first part is what you want to evaluate and goes in the parenthesis of the switch() portion of the statement. The second part (or parts, really) are the constants that the first part will be evaluated against. Those need to be static/constant values to check against. Therefore, you can't use an expression like hand1[1]-hand1[0] - that can and will change during the execution of the program.
You could use if..else chains, however, and probably accomplish what you're looking for.